# In Google Spreadsheets how to avoid figures changing places

Tags: google-sheets

I am using a Google spreadsheet and I insert several images. Since I want to point some places in the image I use a figure (sorry the names are all in Japanese so I don't know if I am using the right terminology) in the shape of a circle over the image.

However, I do this in my ubuntu pc. When I open the same spreadsheet from my windows PC, the images and the circle are all moved incorrectly. This defeats the purpose of the circle.

I tried to join picture and circle as in Microsoft Excel but it doesn't seem possible.

How can I:

- Make sure the images and circles don't move?
  OR
- Join them so that they move together? (not a good solution but still better than the current situation)

Comment: I would add the circles and arrows to the images with something like Greenshot (a screenshot tool which also has a very basic image editor).

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. You said _However, I do this in my ubuntu pc. When I open the same spreadsheet from my windows PC, the images and the circle are all moved incorrectly._ This is a bit confusing because Sheets runs off the net and your operating system shouldn't be a factor, though the zoom size of your screen might be a factor. There are several ways of inserting images, would you please explain EXACTLY how you do it, provide links to the images, and provide a screenshot of the images in ubuntu vs Windows.